# Finding where onclick event is set for a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

By using a web inspector I've found a

```
<div id="logo">
```

which when you click refreshes the page.  It is the containing div for the link logo and image logo.

I don't want this behavior.

How can I find out where it is being set to do this?

It is for the main logo here on the front page here:

[www.papermepress.com](http://www.papermepress.com)

If you notice the whole top is click-able.  I only want the logo to be clickable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't the `<div>` causing your page to refresh, it is the `<a>` contained inside it. The logo is linked to the home page, a universally common practice.

```
<div id="logo" class="grid_24">
  <a href="http://papermepress.com" title="Paper Me"><img src="http://papermepress.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/PMP_logocopy1.png"></a>               
</div>
```

Though its dimensions are much smaller than the parent `<div id='logo'>`, the `<img>` has `display: block;` so the containing `<a>` will fill the entire parent `<div id='logo'>`. If you remove that `display: block;` the containing `<a>` won't expand to fill the whole parent `<div id='logo'>` and only the image area itself will be clickable.

```
/* in style.css */
#logo img {margin:0 auto; text-align:center; display:block; margin:0 auto;}
```

Comment: Sorry but what does #logo img mean?  Does that apply CSS to all #logo and img or all img in #logo?

Comment: Taking out the display:block "breaks" the page.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist `#logo img` in CSS terms means _all `<img>` tags inside the element whose id is `logo`_

Comment: Since it is relying on `display: block;` to center the image, if you remove that CSS attribute, you'll need to come up with another method for centering it horizontally.  There are a few ways to handle it. [Search around here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+center+horizontally) for some methods.